# How to take a backup and restore a subsite?

Tags: sharepoint-server

How to take a backup and restore a sub-site inside a site collection of a SharePoint web application in SharePoint 2010 and 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of Granular backup/restore feature in SP 2010. Or you can also use Export/Import command line to take specific subsite backup.

```
stsadm -o export -url  http://servername:portno/subsitename -filename mysubSiteBackup -includeusersecurity
```

[Reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/russmax/2009/10/21/sharepoint-2010-granular-backup-restore-part-1/)

**Or Else**

Powershell, But you have to make sure both web application have same set of features / solutions etc.Follow the below powershell commands.

- use export-spweb to export the subsite. `export-spweb -identity "http://Subsite url" -path c:\export.cmp`
- Now create a blank subsite on target site collection. Use `new-spweb` powershell. `New-SPWeb http://somesite/subweb1`
- Finally, you have to run the `import-spweb` to import the subsite. `import-spweb -identity "http://Targetsubsite url" -path "c:\export.cmp"`

Answer (score 1):

You backup and restore sites using PowerShell (export-spweb or import-spweb).  You can also perform the backup in Central Admin. please refer to the article.

[how to prepare to back up and restore SharePoint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662536.aspx)